# Select all child record but need values of parent or grandparent record

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm working on a project that uses a MariaDB v5.5 database to keep track of employees in a tree based higherarchy.  Each person in this tree can have various 'flags' associated with them.  In this case, these flags are stored using a bitmask.

My objects look like the following

```
Employee Table description
+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| Name         | Field       | Description                          |
+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| employee_id  | INT         | Unique key                           |
| name         | VARCHAR(45) | Employees name                       |
| flags        | INT(4)      | Bitmask of employee attributes       |
| parent_id    | INT         | the employee_id of the parent record |
+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+

'flag' bitmap description
+-----+--------------+
| Bit | Flag         |
+-----+--------------+
| 0   | CEO          |
| 1   | MANAGER      |
| 2   | PROJECT_LEAD |
| 3   | SALES_PERSON |
| 4   | MAINTANCE    |
+-----+--------------+

Employee Table Data
+----+--------+------------+---------------------------+
| id | name   | parent_id  | flags                     |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------------+
| 1  | Lisa   | NULL       | CEO                       | 
| 2  | Steve  | 1          | MANAGER                   | 
| 3  | Pat    | 1          | MANAGER                   | 
| 4  | Mary   | 2          | SALES_PERSON,PROJECT_LEAD | 
| 5  | Phil   | 4          | SALES_PERSON,MAINTANCE    |
| 6  | Jim    | 3          | SALES_PERSON,MAINTANCE    |
| 7  | Anna   | 3          | SALES_PERSON,MAINTANCE    |
+----+--------+------------+---------------------------+
```

Let's say I want to query all employees who have the "MAINTANCE" flag BUT, I need to return the id of the parent record that has the "MANAGER" flag.  So my result should look like this.

```
> SELECT id, name, manager_id, manager_name FROM ...
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
| ID | Name   | manager_id | manager_name |
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
| 5  | Phil   | 2          | Steve        |
| 6  | Jim    | 3          | Pat          |
| 7  | Anna   | 3          | Pat          |
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
```

So how do I build my query to give me what I want?

Note, that this tree can be more than just 3 levels deep and the query still needs to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
 a.ID
,a.Name
,a.manager_ID
,b.Manager_Name
From
 EmployeeTable As a
Left Join
 EmployeeTable As b
On
 a.Mangager_ID = b.ID
Where
 a.Flag = 'Maintenance'
And
 b.Flag = 'Manager'
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: That only works if the manager is one level above the employee.  Not for cases when the manager is several levels above the employee.  That's the trick.  It's not just one level difference, it's many levels between the employee and the manager.

Comment: Just to check you want to get the managers of the managers as well?

Comment: Not the managers of managers. I want the managers of the MAINTANCE people.  In this case, The manager for Jim and Anna is Pat, who is directly above them.  But the manager of Phil is Steve, who is 2 steps above Phil.  And in some cases, this 'distance' on the tree is more than that.  So the issue is not "Who is directly above me".  This issue is. "Who is the person above me at this level, and they could be 2, 3, or more levels above me."  See it now?

Comment: ah I see it now ok I will have a think as that is arkward